# Discontinuities in taking the roots of a complex function

Tags: complex, discontinuity

I have the following functions `e1`, `e2`, and `e3` which consists of the functions `p`, `u1c`, `u2c`, and `sigc`

```
p = (Γ + κ1 + κ2)/2;
u1c = -36 g1^2 (-2 p + 3 κ2) - (36 g2^2 + (2 p - 3 κ1) (2 p - 3 κ2)) (4 p - 3 (κ1 + κ2));
u2c = 2^(2/3)*(12 g1^2 + 12 g2^2 - 4 p^2 + 6 p (κ1 + κ2) - 3 (κ1^2 + κ1 κ2 + κ2^2));
sigc = (u1c + Sqrt[u1c^2 + u2c^3])^(1/3);

e1 = -(1/3)*(p + u2c/(2^(4/3)*sigc) - 1/2^(4/3)*sigc);
e2 = -(1/3)*(p + E^(-I*π/3)*sigc/2^(4/3) - E^(I*π/3)*u2c/(2^(4/3)*sigc));
e3 = -(1/3)*(p + E^(I*π/3)*sigc/2^(4/3) - E^(-I*π/3)*u2c/(2^(4/3)*sigc));
```

I intend to plot the real part of `e1`, `e2`, and `e3` by fixing the parameters `κ1`, `κ2`, `Γ`, and `g2` as a function of `g1`.

```
ree1 = (Re[ComplexExpand[e1]]) /. {Γ -> 0.01, κ1 -> 1.0, κ2 -> 20, g2 -> 4.8}
ree2 = (Re[ComplexExpand[e2]]) /. {Γ -> 0.01, κ1 -> 1.0, κ2 -> 20, g2 -> 4.8}
ree3 = (Re[ComplexExpand[e3]]) /. {Γ -> 0.01, κ1 -> 1.0, κ2 -> 20, g2 -> 4.8}
```

Upon plotting

```
Plot[{Evaluate@ree1, Evaluate@ree2, Evaluate@ree3}, {g1, 0, 10}, PlotRange -> All, ImageSize -> Large, PlotPoints -> 100, PlotStyle -> {Directive[Black], Directive[Red, Dashed], Directive[Blue, Dotted, Thick]}]
```

I am returned with[image]

There is a peculiar behavior with `ree1` (black curve) in that it jumps around `g1 = 3` (x-axis), something that shouldn't happen. I tried only plotting `ree1` and I have that
[image]

Given that I have already specified for only Real parts of `e1`, there shouldn't be any discontinuity. I suspect that this has to do with `sigc` since there is a radical in there followed by an overall cube root and Mathematica probably doesn't know which root to take when the quantity in the radical becomes less than 0 (taking the cube root of a complex number). I know that the final plot should display the curves with no discontinuities and it is likely that the red and black curves swapped positions at around `g1 = 3`. How should I go about remedying this problem?

**Edit:** I have tried using `Surd` but it does not work when the quantity inside the cube root in `sigc` is complex since `Surd` only takes in real valued quantities.